# Will the compiler unroll this loop?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, compiler-optimization

I am creating a multi-dimensional vector (mathematical vector) where I allow basic mathematical operations +,-,/,*,=. The template takes in two parameters, one is the type (int, float etc.) while the other is the size of the vector. Currently I am applying the operations via a for loop. Now considering the size is known at compile time, will the compiler unroll the loop? If not, is there a way to unroll it with no (or minimal) performance penalty?

```
template <typename T, u32 size>
class Vector
{
public:
    // Various functions for mathematical operations. 
    // The functions take in a Vector<T, size>.
    // Example:
    void add(const Vector<T, size>& vec)
    {
        for (u32 i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        {
            values[i] += vec[i];
        }
    }

private:
    T   values[size];
};
```

Before somebody comments `Profile then optimize` please note that this is the basis for my 3D graphics engine and it must be fast. Second, I want to know for the sake of educating myself.

Comment: Not to sound snarky, but if you compile with optimizations and dump the assembly you can pretty much find out :)

Comment: Even if it must be really fast, profiling is an invaluable tool. In fact, it's your fest friend *especially* if has to be really fast, because it works much better than guessing. (Also, the answer might depend heavily on the compiler, the flags used and perhaps even more.)

Comment: `If not, is there a way to unroll it with no (or minimal) performance penalty?` The entire point of unrolling a loop is to increase performance...why would you do it if it cost performance?

Comment: Minor correction: this won't compile because your class declaration is missing a semicolon. It's also pretty standard to use camelCase for methods.

Comment: Side remark: why are you using `u32` (whatever that may be, but I can do an educated guess) instead of `size_t` for the size of an object?

Comment: Also, your code doesn't add, it assigns.

Comment: Note that loop unrolling isn't necessarily a win, particularly on more recent x86 CPUs

Comment: @larsman: If you have more than 4 billion points in a 3-D model, you have bigger problems than using a 32-bit count.  (Besides which, the GPU driver probably has hardcoded a 32-bit count.)

Comment: This indeed smells like premature optimization. Make your graphics engine work first. Then profile and optimize. I would guess that this bit of code isn't going to be your bottleneck.

Comment: @Paul: Full loop unrolling may not be, but a small unrolling factor such as 4x likely is.  Especially if SSE operations can then be used to copy the data.

Comment: @Bart: You don't mean to suggest that the vector add operator should actually *add* (and not merely *copy*) its operand, do you?  Next thing you know, people will be preaching about *correctness*.

Comment: @Ben Voigt Never. Didn't Dijkstra say about the competent programmer "He therefore approaches his task with full humility, and avoids correctness like the plague"?... ;)

Comment: @Bart: oooh that's a perfect quote for this -- if you quote correctly, you avoid clever tricks, and if you quote cleverly, you avoid correctness.  Pure win.

Comment: @Bart: The engine is working. I was working with a third party Math library and am switching over to my own classes. This is a question that came to my mind when I was writing the vector classes (which consist of Vector2, Vector3 and Vector4) and I was wondering if I could get away with on Vector that is able to satisfy all Vector types mentioned.

Comment: You should not even be asking the question. The compiler (when optimizing for speed) will pick the optimum way to do it. The optimum way may not be to unroll the loop. The compiler is good at these things let it work out the best way. Trying to optimize it yourself will only make the code slower (you can equal the compiler but are unlikely ever to beat it).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do the following trick with disassembly to see how the particular code is compiled.

```
    Vector<int, 16> a, b;
    Vector<int, 65536> c, d;

    asm("xxx"); // marker
    a.Add(b);
    asm("yyy"); // marker
    c.Add(d);
    asm("zzz"); // marker
```

Now compile

```
gcc -O3 1.cc -S -o 1.s
```

And see the disasm

```
    xxx
# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
    movdqa  524248(%rsp), %xmm0
    leaq    524248(%rsp), %rsi
    paddd   524184(%rsp), %xmm0
    movdqa  %xmm0, 524248(%rsp)
    movdqa  524264(%rsp), %xmm0
    paddd   524200(%rsp), %xmm0
    movdqa  %xmm0, 524264(%rsp)
    movdqa  524280(%rsp), %xmm0
    paddd   524216(%rsp), %xmm0
    movdqa  %xmm0, 524280(%rsp)
    movdqa  524296(%rsp), %xmm0
    paddd   524232(%rsp), %xmm0
    movdqa  %xmm0, 524296(%rsp)
#APP
# 36 "1.cc" 1
    yyy
# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
    leaq    262040(%rsp), %rdx
    leaq    -104(%rsp), %rcx
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L2:
    movdqa  (%rcx,%rax), %xmm0
    paddd   (%rdx,%rax), %xmm0
    movdqa  %xmm0, (%rdx,%rax)
    addq    $16, %rax
    cmpq    $262144, %rax
    jne .L2
#APP
# 38 "1.cc" 1
    zzz
```

As you see, the first loop was small enough to get unrolled. The second is the loop.

Answer (score 6):

First:  Modern CPUs are pretty smart about predicting branches, so unrolling the loop might not help (and could even hurt).

Second:  Yes, modern compilers know how to unroll a loop like this, if it is a good idea for your target CPU.

Third: Modern compilers can even auto-vectorize the loop, which is even better than unrolling.

Bottom line: Do not think you are smarter than your compiler unless you know a **lot** about CPU architecture.  Write your code in a simple, straightforward way, and do not worry about micro-optimizations until your profiler tells you to.

Answer (score 2):

The loop can be unrolled using recursive template instantiation. This may or may not be faster on your C++ implementation.

I adjusted your example slightly, so that it would compile.

```
typedef unsigned u32; // or something similar

template <typename T, u32 size>
class Vector
{
  // need to use an inner class, because member templates of an 
  // unspecialized template cannot be explicitly specialized.
  template<typename Vec, u32 index>
  struct Inner
  {
    static void add(const Vec& a, const Vec& b)
    {
      a.values[index] = b.values[index];
      // triggers recursive instantiation of Inner 
      Inner<Vec, index-1>::add(a,b);
    }
  };
  // this specialization terminates the recursion
  template<typename Vec>
  struct Inner<Vec, 0>
  {
    static void add(const Vec& a, const Vec& b)
    {
      a.values[0] = b.values[0];
    }
  };

public:

    // PS! this function should probably take a 
    // _const_ Vector, because the argument is not modified
    // Various functions for mathematical operations. 
    // The functions take in a Vector<T, size>.
    // Example:
    void add(Vector<T, size>& vec)
    {
      Inner<Vector, size-1>::add(*this, vec);
    }

    T   values[size];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is not at all certain that unrolling the loop would be beneficial.

The only possible answer to your question is "it depends" (on the compiler flags, on the value of `size`, etc).

If you really want to know, ask your compiler: compile into assembly code with typical values of `size` and with the optimization flags you'd use for real, and examine the result.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to figure this out is to try it on your own compiler with your own optimization parameters. Make one test file with your "does it unroll" code, `test.cpp`:

```
#include "myclass.hpp"

void doSomething(Vector<double, 3>& a, Vector<double, 3>& b) {
    a.add( b );
}
```

then a reference code snippet `reference.cpp`:

```
#include "myclass.hpp"

void doSomething(Vector<double, 3>& a, Vector<double, 3>& b) {
    a[0] += b[0];
    a[1] += b[1];
    a[2] += b[2];
}
```

and now use GCC to compile them and spit out only the assembly:

```
for x in *.cpp; do  g++ -c "$x" -Wall -Wextra -O2 -S -o "out/$x.s"; done
```

In my experience, GCC will unroll loops of 3 or less by default when using loops whose duration are known at compile time; using the `-funroll-loops` will cause it to unroll even more.

Answer (score 0):

Many compilers will unroll this loop, no idea if "the compiler" you are referring to will.  There isn't just one compiler in the world.

If you want to guarantee that it's unrolled, then TMP (with inlining) can do that.  (This is actually one of the more trivial applications of TMP, often used as an example of metaprogramming).

Comment: I have added the relevant tag. It is the MSVC compiler.

Comment: @Samarusa: There is no "the compiler".  You know how many flavors of MSVC there are?  Add the version string (printed by the compiler when you run `cl.exe /version`) to your question.